# Uploaded photos not showing up on Timeline Feed

Tags: facebook-pages

I have some problems with some photos [single photos] that I have uploaded on a Facebook Page. Although they upload correctly, they do not appear on my Page Timeline even if they have a date on them. They do show on PHOTOS, if clicked on to see, and I know these non-timeline photos are going into newsfeeds, b/c of 'likes/comments/shares"

Ideas?

Comment: I'd say it depends on your settings and on what process or application you used to upload those photos. Easiest way to "fix" the issue now is to _Share_ the album or photos onto the page.

Comment: Thanks, slubloty - that addresses getting an existing post into the timeline...but what I'm seeking is to have it right the first time...and I'm thinking it's something new/FB quarky. Nothing different about how I put up these posts than with previous posts...

Comment: Same thing just happened to a new cover photo I uploaded. It shows up in the newsfeed. Friend "like"d it, but it's invisible on my timeline. (Though I can click on black space to get to it). Date is today. Brand new. Could this be the same bug?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out:  Ensure the photo is dated, and that the date the photo was taken is indicated as the actual day you're posting (you can input this information when you edit the photo).